# How do I store this object in my iOS class?

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary

I am creating my first Master-Detail application for iOS.

I want to store the following

1. Name
2. Web URL

In my UITableView, I plan on displaying only the name (sorted) but when the name is tapped, another view will load with a button that will launch Safari with the WebURL

I tried using an MSMutableArray but discovered it's not sortable. Same is true with an NSDictionary.

Any ideas (or sample or links to samples) would be appreciated

I am trying to use methods that are not deprecated in iOS 7.0
and plan on supporting iOS 6

earlier versions are a + but I can live without support for 3,4,5.

Comment: You can most certainly sort an NS(Mutable)Array.  But presumably you want to sort the pair of entities vs just the names or just the URLs.  For that I'd probably place the two in a dictionary, place the dictionaries in an array, and use one of the "sortedArrayUsing..." methods to sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An NSMutableArray with an NSDictionary for each item is perfectly fine. You can sort it.

```
NSMutableArray *rows = @[].mutableCopy;
[rows addObject:@{@"name": @"Bob", @"url": [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://bob.com"]}];
[rows addObject:@{@"name": @"Alice", @"url": [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://alice.net"]}];
NSLog(@"%@", rows);

[rows sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
  return [[obj1 valueForKey:@"name"] compare:[obj2 valueForKey:@"name"] options:NSNumericSearch];
}];
NSLog(@"%@", rows);
```

Output:

```
2013-07-20 00:33:31.682 MyApp[28496:303] (
        {
        name = Bob;
        url = "http://bob.com";
    },
        {
        name = Alice;
        url = "http://alice.net";
    }
)
2013-07-20 00:33:31.682 MyApp[28496:303] (
        {
        name = Alice;
        url = "http://alice.net";
    },
        {
        name = Bob;
        url = "http://bob.com";
    }
)
```

Comment: If I create a class and have properties for the data for an object. Can I use the class as a row in my UITableView? Then I can keep an NSArray of my custom objects

Comment: You can use anything you want as the data for your table view. You are responsible for building each cell in the cellForRow delegate method. What data backs it up is up to you, an array of custom objects is a common choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort NSArrays, you just have to write the comparison function yourself because NSArrays store objects, and how to you sort objects that contain potentially thousands of values. There is a good post about it here. That should hopefully get the job done.

[How to sort an NSMutableArray with custom objects in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it)